# Client-Server Architectural Decision

Tags: php, ajax, curl, architecture, client-server

This is less of a troubleshooting question and more of an industry standards question.

I am at a crossroads where architectural standards need to be addressed and implemented.  One of these standards involves the communication route between the client application (AngularJS based, so single-page persistent with multiple views) and third party sources of information.

To me, it seems intuitive and logical to route all requests for third party libraries and data through my backend and then off to various destinations via `CURL`.

In this way, my server acts as a gateway between the client and the outside world (much like the relationship between a cellphone tower router and a cellphone).

I am curious as to what industry standards would say about this, and the potential pitfalls. To me, it seems like it would create more order, organization, and security long term.

Please let me know what your thoughts are regarding this, as I need outside perspectives.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Is it a data streaming application? Do you need any kind of elaboration of those data / [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)?

Comment: B2B, no data streams.  Everything is async and session based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if this counts, as I am not aware of any industry standards - but I interpret it as what you're really asking for is general outside perspective. So here goes:

My short answer is that I think you're on the right track.

I think it's cleaner as it keeps the data path simple in that your client always sends requests to your server - so basically you're getting very loose coupling between your client and everything else (except towards the controller on the server, which is fine, even necessary IMO). Want to change the data source later? Client isn't affected (unless the format differs of course). It's also beneficial if you can picture yourself wanting to store the raw data in a DB for some reason some time in the future. Depending on what services you're connecting to and what you want to do with the data, going through your own server can have security benefits (like if you need to use a private key for authentication against the 3rd party service, like one has to with APIs like those MasterCard offer).

There is a performance hit though, as it gives your server more to do and requires a bit more memory, in addition to the extra requests and DNS look-ups incurred. Then again, you would be in control of caching, so you could possibly make the service slightly more robust in some cases.

So unless performance is paramount, I would go the route you were thinking of. Exactly how the routing is done on your server is a different question and might require some testing. Just make sure you use a method that lets you elegantly handle any errors that might pop up :)